# Get Artifactory artifact by Jenkins build number

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm investigating a Maven/Jenkins/Artifactory set up as a possible solution for a CI/Release process.

I have a job in Jenkins - call it MYJOB - that builds and deploys an artifact to Artifactory. Now, I want another job that I can run manually that will copy the artifact of a particular build of MYJOB from Artifactory and put it somewhere (not too bothered where right now, but eventually it'll be another server).

For example, let's say build #123 went green, and now my QA team want to deploy the built artifact to their environment for further testing (the idea being to keep this artifact intact and unchanged throughout the testing process, before marking it as releasable). I want them to be able to enter '123' into Jenkins as a job parameter and then kick off the build.

So, I figure I need a free-style job that uses a script to do this.

My question is: How can I pass the number of a previous MYJOB build to the job, so that it will get the correct artifact from artifactory?

Alternative methods of achieving my goal are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working. I put the following code in the Build Step section of a Jenkins Freestyle Build Configuration after defining a parameter called 'REQ_BUILD_NUMBER':

```
SOMETHING=$(curl "http://MYARTIFACTORYLOCATION/artifactory/api/search/prop?build.number=$REQ_BUILD_NUMBER"  | jq --raw-output '.results[0].uri')
echo $SOMETHING
SOMETHING_ELSE=$(curl $SOMETHING | jq --raw-output '.downloadUri')
echo $SOMETHING_ELSE
wget -N --directory-prefix=/var/lib/jenkins/artifacts/ $SOMETHING_ELSE
```

(NB: I'm barely competent at shell scripting. I'm sure it can be done in a better way)

EDIT: This requires installing 'jq' for the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Parameterized build for the second job. The QA team can put the build number when they start the build. This build number will be available as an environment variable which can be accessed in the scripts which can then retrieve the packages from the repository.

Comment: How I can use this to call Artifactory?